# gnuplot: putting numbers on each bar

Tags: gnuplot

I have few simple bar charts here. I find it kind of difficult to read out the exact value or even the approximate value of each bar. So it would be nice to have the exact number written into or above the bar, as shown in the attached image:

[image: as shown in the attached image]

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Can you share your code and data file with us, so that we don't need to start from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I have created a file `so.dat` with mock data, namely

```
1 1
2 1.25
3 4.5
4 7
```

If you now use the command

```
plot [0:5][0:8] "so.dat" using 1:2 with boxes, "" u 1:(2):2 w labels
```

you get

[image]

The instruction `"" u 1:(2):2 w labels` tells gnuplot

- to use the same input file,
- to create labels,
- to put them on a location on the x axis that is determined by the first data column in that file,
- to place them at a level of 2 on the y axis,
- and to read the data for the labels from the second column in the data file.

You could also put the labels relative to the box height - try `u 1:($2-.5):2`.

This should get you started. Color and direction of the labels, style of the boxes, axis labels, legend etc. can be customised as much as you like, but we would need a bit more information here - hence the barebone reply.

Comment: thanks for your quick and detailed answer! `w labels` seems to do the trick.